# How to kill Intent data

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that has several activities. The main activity can receive data via Intent, then start another activity that process that data.

I have a problem when finished the second activity, since the main activity runs the onResume method (where check and intentions of the process), and the original intention is still alive. So App calls the second activity again.

My question is to eliminate the Intent data after calling second activity, and thus the return of second intention not to repeat the cycle.

Thank you very much

Comment: This seems like  a similar question from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent

Answer (score 0):

set a class variable to 0 and then make it 1 instead.
So you don't do the looping.

Comment: How you would you then handle another legitimate, unexecuted intent coming in from the outside?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I eliminate the Intent data after calling second activity

yes.

As soon as you call second activity(Or the second activity is started), first activity `onPause` method will be called. You can override `onPause` method in Activity1 and do what ever you like to do.

Ex:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getIntent().removeExtra("YourMainActivityData");
}
```

Comment: That's not a meaningful answer until you suggest something to do in onPause() which will solve the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Then I should say, that's not meaningful question. If you don't provide any code, I assume that you can handle coding  part if you know how to do it. If you  want proper solution with coding, update your question with some details of main activity intent data and how you are handling that data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton sorry,I thought you were the person who asked the question. Anyhow I updated my answer with code. In fact question is not proper. If I give random code, it will misguide readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code after u start second activity in `onResume`:

```
setIntent(new Intent());
```

this will replace the return intent when u call `getIntent()`;

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this. Thank you very much. I got a nullPointerException error, so I add `if (intent!=null)`. With this solution, the second time I click a link, the app don't call its second activity, stay at Main activity. The new Intent is missing, I don't understand it

Answer (score 0):

I can't remove Intent data, so I wrote an alternative method. I did set the intent-filter at  the second activity, and this activity does all the work. When user wants to go back, I start first activity and finih second one.

Perhaps it's a good method, perhaps not is. But it runs OK for me.

Thank you very much!