# Activity receives the same intent after recreation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have 2 activities:

1. `HomeActivity`
2. `OtherActivity`

When push arrives it suppose to start `OtherActivity` by clicking on it but also loads `MainActivity` in background, so when the user will press the back button (from `OtherActivity`) he will be redirect to `HomeActivity`.

```
public class ActivityHome extends AppCompactActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mMainContainerLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        handleLoadFromNotification();

        // Loading fragment
        FragmentHome fragment = new FragmentHome();
        fragmentTransaction(0, fragment, animation, false, FragmentHome.class.getSimpleName());
    }


    private boolean handleLoadFromNotification() {

        boolean isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromNotification", false);

        if (isFromNotification) {

            // Enter from notification
            int typeOfNotification = getIntent().getIntExtra("type", 0);
            Intent intent = null;

            if (typeOfNotification == GCMNotificationIntentService.NOTIFICATION_1) {
                // Form notification
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityForm.class);
                String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
                if (formId != null) {
                intent.putExtra("formId", formId);
            }
        } 

        if (intent != null) {

            // Open activity of notification
            intent.putExtra("isFromNotification", isFromNotification);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            loadActivity(true, null, intent);
        }

        return isFromNotification;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadActivity(boolean supportBack, int[] animation, Intent intent) {

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        // Staring activity
        startActivity(intent);

        if (animation != null) {
            overridePendingTransition(animation[0], animation[1]);
        }

        // Check if need to support the back button
        if (!supportBack) {
            // Close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

`OtherActivity`it's just another activity with some UI, nothing special in it.

Here is how I'm sending the notifications:

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_CHAT = 1; 

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GCMNotificationIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Check if user at home screen by checking the current front    application activity
        Activity currentActivity = ((AppController)getApplication()).getCurrentActivity();

        atHome = false;
        if (currentActivity != null) {
            atHome = currentActivity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(ActivityHome.class.getSimpleName());
        }


        Bundle extras;
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

        extras = intent.getExtras();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        // Check the status of the connection to gcm
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
    //                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
    //                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {


                Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                String msg, type;


                if (keys.contains("data")) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(extras.getString("data"));
                        msg = json.getString("body");
                        type = json.getString("event");


                        if (type.equals("Form")){
                            // get form id
                            String formId;
                            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
                            id = data.getString(0);
                            sendNotification(msg, NOTIFICATION_1, id);
                        } 
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg, int type, String data) {

         // Send the notification to the device

         boolean loggedIn =    ModelPatient.getInstance().getUserId(getApplicationContext()) != null;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = null;

        // Check if user is logged in before sending push
        if (loggedIn){
                intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHome.class);
                intent.putExtra("isFromNotification", true);
                intent.putExtra("type", NOTIFICATION_1);
                intent.putExtra("id", data);
        }

        if (!atHome && intent != null) {
            notify(msg, type, intent);
        }
    }
}

    private void notify(String msg, int type, Intent intent) {

        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setContentTitle("New Title")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setLights(PURPLE, 500, 500)                                               .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setContentText(msg);

         mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
         mNotificationManager.notify(type, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

***The Issue:***

When I'm doing the the following:

```
1.Application in background
2.Got new push
3.Click on push in the notification drawer
4.OtherActivity is shown as expected
5.Press back button (Now HomeActivity is in front)
6.Press back button again (App is in background)
7.Enter app via application stack
```

Now `HomeActivity` should start without `OtherActivity`, but `OtherActivity` it shown also! - onCreate is starts with the same intent sent by notificationManager when clicking on the notification.
If in step 6, I'm exit app by clicking the home button and then go back to activity as step 7 describes everything seems to be ok.

In general the problem is that the application some how keep this intent when enter back app from the stack.

I've tried to change the `PendingIntent`'s and `Intent`'s flags but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I've already explained this is gory detail. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/769265

Comment: @DavidWasser thanks for your replay. I finally solved it by user StackBuilder.

Comment: @sharonooo Just using task builder solves this problem?

Answer (score 1):

difference between exit your App in step 6. by pressing BACK and HOME is that BACK calls finish() and onDestroy(), respectively, and HOME set your Activity to onPause() state.

From http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

> There are a few scenarios in which your activity is destroyed due to
>   normal app behavior, such as when the user presses the Back button or
>   your activity signals its own destruction by calling finish().

And when onCreate() is called, OtherActivity has chance to start.

Try to use in GCMNotificationIntentService:notify() following flags:

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent contentIntent;
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, 0);
```