# Pending intent extras are not cleared even if activity is re created

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent, android-bundle

I have widget in which I have speak button. On pressing speak button on widget I am opening MainActivity which is declared single top in manifest.

Following is code on speak widget button

```
Intent speakIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
speakIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
speakIntent.putExtra(Constants.IS_LAUNCH_SPEAK, true);
speakIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_SPEAK_SCREEN);
PendingIntent configSpeakPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, Utils.generateRandom(), speakIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(
            R.id.btn_speak, configSpeakPendingIntent);
```

This opens google speak dialog and works fine.

But if I press back on this dialog and minimize the app by pressing back button  on resuming app again it shows speak dialog even though app is not started from widget

SO intent extras are not getting cleared even though activity is destoyed I also tried clearing extras by using removeExtra but this is also not working

Since activity has singletop launch mode in manifest I checked if OnNewIntent is getting called or not but OnNewIntent is not getting called oncreate is getting called on resuming app

Intent extras are not getting clear when calling from widget event though activity is destoyed and removeExtra is not working

How to fix this.

Same thing happening when opening activity through notification following is code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Constants.SOME_VALUE, value);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Utils.generateRandom() /* Request code */, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: try also using PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT  in conjunction with the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: so PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

the one shot flag will make sure that the particular pending intent will only be used once

Comment: tried it is also not working

Comment: Please see this similar question and my answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/769265

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with my widget.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after you put constants

`callBack.getActivity().clearLaunchIntent();`

Call clearLaunchIntent() from your activity

```
public void clearLaunchIntent() { this.lastLaunchIntent = null; }
```

Hope this will help