# Avoid caching Intent Extras after App is closed with back press

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I start my app through a PendingIntent that comes from a notification and looks likes this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
    (getApplicationContext(), 1 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

I set an extra so that a specific task is performed and get it via:

```
GcmListenerService.PushNotificationTrigger pushNotificationTrigger = (GcmListenerService.PushNotificationTrigger) intent.getSerializableExtra(
            GcmListenerService.GCM_PUSH_TRIGGER_KEY);
```

After the task is performed, I "close" the app via back press (simple onBackPressed). When opening the app again, it performs the task again. I debugged it and came to the result, that the pushNotificationTrigger is still the same. The Intent had the same extras as before I closed it. It seems to me, like Android caches it.

*What I already tried and what didn't worked:*

Removing the extra, after it was read the first time with:

```
intent.removeExtra(GcmListenerService.GCM_PUSH_TRIGGER_KEY);
```

Overriding onBackPressed with finish()

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: press back button just force your activity to go to background, it doesn´t close it. If you want to close it, call finish() in onBackPressed.....

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Opiatefuchs I tried this, but it didn't work either.

Comment: ok, not really clear....do you want to have another intent or don´t you want to perform the task again?

Comment: To make it clear: I want to start again in the normal way the activity starts, without having that extra within the Intent. The task should not be performed again, but it does for now.

Comment: please show more of your code, from the posted snippet we can´t see the problem....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs you are not correct. The default behaviour of `onBackPressed()` is to call `finish()`. This is standard Android behaviour and you do not need to override `onBackPressed()` to call `finishI()`, that is useless. When you press the BACK key, this does NOT put your app in the background, it finishes the current `Activity`. Maybe you should write a simple test program with 3 activities and try it yourself.

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent for more information about how to deal with this problem.