# When I add Extras to PendinIntent from Notification, RemoveExtras has no effect

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

My problem is quite simple to explain:

I create a notification from a push service and start my activity with some extras:

```
notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
notificationIntent.putExtra("typeI",data.get("type"));

Log.e("DEBUG","PUT EXTRA");

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

So, when I click my notification, I can read the type in my activity:

```
Log.e("DEBUG", "Extra -> " + getIntent().getStringExtra("typeI"));
```

And this is working fine.

The only annoyance is that I quit the application with the back button, Activity is destroyed, and when launching it again from the Launcher, I still get the extras!

So, I just tried to remove the extras, in my ACtivity, just after reading them just in case:

```
Log.e("DEBUG","REMOVE");
getIntent().removeExtra("typeI");
getIntent().putExtra("typeI","");
```

But that doesn't remove the extras, and next time I open the application Extras are still there.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add manifest entry of your activity .

Comment: Ooooh thats strange but if you are using a service to get a notification then why not using `YourServiceName.this` instead of `getBaseContext()`! Isn't that a problem!

Comment: @ADM:  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I removed singleInstance just in case, but no effect, I still have extras in onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the "extras", this only removes the "extras" in the "in-memory instance of the `Intent`". The original `Intent` is still persisted by Android and is reused when you launch the app again.

This is a bug, or a feature, depending on what you are trying to do.

I wrote a rather lengthly response to a similar question in 2013. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent/19820057#19820057). You probably want to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`.

You also shouldn't need to use `launchMode="singleInstance"`. This special launch mode is not necessary unless you are writing a HOME-screen replacement.

---

**EDIT:** You indicated in a comment that this didn't work for you. I think the problem is that you are using your root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) in the `Notification`. Try this instead:

For the `Notification`, don't use `MainActivity`, but `NotificationActivity`. Define `NotificationActivity` as an **alias** for `MainActivity` in the manifest like this:

```
<activity-alias
    android:name=".NotificationActivity"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
</activity>
```

This entry should **not** contain any `<intent-filter>` and must appear **after** the manifest entry for `MainActivity`.

Comment: Your answer look awesome, I will try tomorrow, (many chances I will accept your answer as it looks great) and I am really looking forward your long explanation, is there a missing link, or is it just that I don't see it?

Comment: So sorry, I forgot to link to the answer! I've added the link to the answer and here it is again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent/19820057#19820057

Comment: Were you able to try this? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Arf, I accepted the answer, but the Intent is still keeping the extras (I removed the singleinstance, and added the flag)

Comment: notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);}

            notificationIntent.putExtra("typeI",data.get("type"));

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: I've edited my answer with an update. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

try this this

```
getIntent().replaceExtras(new Bundle());
getIntent().setData(null);
after this add you value
getIntent().putExtra("typeI","");
```

Comment: replacing the previous bundle with a emplty bunle  will erase the data and now can put the new data

Comment: Despite the fact that I repaced all the extra, getExtra in onCreate has still some extras even after I exit the app with back! I am completely lost here...

Comment: This only replaces the "extras" in the "in-memory instance of the `Intent`". Android has persisted the original `Intent` and will reuse that when the user opens the app again. This is no help.

Comment: This code still only updates the "extras" in the "in-memory instance of the `Intent`". This won't help.