# Intent's parameter always been keep when enter from task manager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I use short cut to start an activity with an action and parameters.

```
    fun makeShortcut(id: String, @StringRes shortLabel: Int, @StringRes longLabel: Int,
                         @DrawableRes icon: Int, action: String, cmd: String): ShortcutInfo {

            return ShortcutInfo.Builder(context(), id)
                    .setShortLabel(context().getString(shortLabel))
                    .setLongLabel(context().getString(longLabel))
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context(), icon))
                    .setIntents(arrayOf(
                            Intent(action).putExtra(KEY_CMD, cmd)
                    ))
                    .build()
        }
```

After starting the activity, I do some stuff and finish the activity.
The I launch the activity from task manager. The value passed by **KEY_CMD** is still exists. I want to clear the values when activity enter from task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a bug or a feature of Android, depending on how you expect things to work. For you it obviously is more of a bug than a feature. See my detailed analysis of a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/769265)

To solve your problem you could try creating an `<activity-alias>` that you use for the shortcut. The `<activity-alias>` points to the same `<activity>` that you use as your main launcher, but you can specify different flags and behaviour. If you specify `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the `<activity-alias>` and use the `<activity-alias>` in your shortcut, this should solve your problem.

If your entire application contains only one single `Activity`, then you could probably easily solve your problem by adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` for your `Activity` in the manifest (in this case you don't need the `<activity-alias>`).