# The intent data remains, when I close the app by the back button and restart from the task

Tags: android, android-intent

I developed a deep link app.
The intent data remains, when I close the app by the back button and restart from the task After launching from deep link.

Manifest:

```
<application
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="news"
                android:scheme="example" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".NextActivity" />

</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW && Uri.parse(intent.data.toString()).host == "news") {
            // Transition NextActivity
        }
    }
}
```

In case of startup after closing with the back button, the code of "Transition Next Activity" is passed many times.

I tried this but did not work.

```
intent.data = null
setIntent(intent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered a similar question about "extras" in an `Intent` in a `Notification`. The problem is the same. When you launch an app for the first time (in your case via deep link), Android remembers the `Intent` that was used to launch the app. When your user returns to the app from the "recent tasks" list, Android launches the app using the same (remembered) `Intent`. To get around this you have 2 options:

1. Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` in your deep-link. This will prevent the task from showing up in the list of recent tasks and therefore precent the deep-link `Intent` from being remembered.
2. Detect `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`. When the user launches an app from the list of recent tasks, Android adds this flag to the `Intent` that is passed to your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. You can check for the existence of this flag, and if it is set, you can clear the data from the `Intent` so that your app does not perform the same actions as when launched by deep-link.

See my answer here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/769265

Comment: Thanks! I solved by checking `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY `.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this answer was helpful you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. That will help others who may have a similar problem and get this question off the list of open questions. It increases your "accept rate" and gives me some reputation points. Something for everyone!