# Pending intent stays after leaving activity with back button

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm using pending intent with notification to send a push to my device.

My pending intent contains fields that will be used in my `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method to handle navigation. After successful navigation to any point in my application I tapping on the back button until my app goes to the background. Right after that my activity instantly invokes `onDestroy()` for some reasons (using android emulator API 28). The problem is that after lifting up app to the foreground, PendingIntent still there and my app performs navigation again.

It's really strange. I always thought that intents with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` could be used only once. I also tried to clear intent by myself but it didn't work out too.

My Intent construction

```
const val NAVIGATION_BUDNLE = "nav_bundle"

private fun createPendingIntent(): PendingIntent? {
    val destination = resolveDestionation()

    val intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        putExtra(NAVIGATION_BUDNLE, destination)
    }

    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Random.nextInt(), intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
}
```

At the end of the activity `onCreate()` method, I've got these lines to handle navigation.

```
intent?.extras?.get(NAVIGATION_BUNDLE)?.let {
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, it as Bundle)
    clearCurrentIntent() // intent = null and intent?.extras?.remove(NAVIGATION_BUNDLE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to my answer! You should please copy your edit into an answer and answer your own question and then accept that answer. That will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions and may also help other developers with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it (great thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent/19820057#19820057) answer)! So this behavior can happen if you leave your activity with back button press. In this cases your activity will call `onDestroy()` method without calling `onSaveInstanceState()` and you will receive same intent over and over again (while clicking back to quit your app, of course). All you need to do is check if your app was called from recent. To do that you can implement this check before your main activity reading your intent:

```
    if (intent.flags and FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY == 0) {
        intent?.extras?.get(NAVIGATION_BUNDLE)?.let {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, it as Bundle)
        }
    }
```

Flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` will appear if your app is launched from recent and that's a very tiny workaround for this particular problem. If this flag presented just don't read your intent and that's it.